# Preventing dangerous user input from django tinymce

Tags: html, django, tinymce

Say we want to use tinymce to allow users to enter HTML formatted input. The django-tinymce package is a handy solution.

But to render this later as output, we have to use {{ userinput | safe }} to display it. But do we know for a fact the original user's input is ... safe?

What in particular are the kinds of malicious HTML tags we need to be wary of and sanitize? What would be a sound strategy to not strip out the legitimate tags tinymce utilizes while protecting future website users who will be presented with 'safe' user input?

Comment: The opposite of `|safe` is `|escape`. It just will transform `<` to `&lt;`, `>` to `&gt;`, `"` to `&quot;`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can never assume that data provided to you client side is "clean" or "safe".  Nefarious people can bypass your front end and all of its validation if their goal is to cause harm to your system.

You should always configure your front end appropriately.  Validate data, configure TinyMCE to only allow those types of tags you want created, etc.

However, regardless of the front end design, you always have to re-check submitted content on the server to be safe. There is simply no way around that need.  What constitutes "safe" is likely a business decision based on what your application does and who uses it.

There are many different libraries you can use server side to do this sort of validation/cleansing so depending on your specific server side setup (guessing PHP) you can find libraries that allow you to "sanitize/purify" the submitted HTML.